# Android fastest drawing layout for a list row

Tags: android, xml, listview, optimization, layout

I'm creating a list view that I want to scroll smoothly.

I am currently designing the row in my XML file, and am wondering which layout view to choose. I want a row layout similar to this:

[image]

Mine will have an `ImageView` on the left, then two rows of `TextView`'s on top of each other. (The orb on that picture *isn't* needed)

So what is the most efficient (when it comes to drawing) layout to use? Options I'm considering are `TableLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` (horizontal).

---

**Extra info:**
My list adapter is already very efficient and uses the viewholder pattern as well as pre-computation of `TextView` textand other optimisations to get maximum efficiency there. This question was specifically about the *layout* of the list row, though your help is appreciated!

Comment: Android and ListView itself is well optimized so you shouldn't be worried about things like this. Chose what you want :)

Comment: As mentioned in answers below, RelativeLayout is the best solution. If you want to make the listView efficient you should consider using ViewHolder Pattern to reduce using 'findViewById()' method. Very good explanation is placed here http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Comment: @MP23 Link you posted is broken now. I've change my blog url http://jmanzano.me/efficient-listviews-in-android-viewholder-pattern-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a `RelativeLayout` so you can choose where to place every single component. Basically, on the left side the imageview, then 2 textview one above the other. Optionally, the image on the right side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Medium Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/first_txt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first_txt"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#0481ab"
        android:text="Small Text"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A `RelativeLayout` is indeed the best choice in terms of performance for this kind of layout. If you want to know why, have a look at this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to:

1. Use a `Spannable` for showing all text as markup in one `TextView`.
2. The image(?) on right can be set as a right `CompoundDrawable` for the above `TextView`.
3. Set `android:drawingCacheQuality="low"` if you don't have fancy gradients in background.
4. Don't do something heavy in Adapter's `getView()`, if you did Override it.